# Передать Geometry Group в VM

Tags: c#, mvvm

У меня есть такой код формы.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel();
    }
 }
```

Мне нужно во VM передать Geometry Group,
Сейчас я сделал так:

```
DataContext = new ApplicationViewModel(geometryGroup);
```

Но не знаю является ли такое решение уместным для паттерна MVVM?

**ps** Не могу найти инфу по передаче gg,есть только вопросы без ответа на англ. СО

Comment: Ни одному элементу из вида нечего делать во вьюмодели. В общих чертах вьюмодель знает **что** отображать (предоставляет данные для отображения), но **не знает как** их отрисовать. Так что знание вм о GeometryGroup не MVVM-но.

Comment: @vitidev Спасибо